# Dagger2 - should an activity component be a sub-component of other?

Tags: dagger-2

I used `@subcomponent` mostly for case activities need to use some shared objects from application component, or fragments components want to use some objects provided by container activity.

Now I am wondering if I can make some activity components be `subcomponent` of another activity component. For example, the `TaskDetailActivity` has a task object and want to provide to some other activities such as `TaskParticipantActivity`, `TaskProgressActivity` and some fragments.

The traditional way to provide task object to other activities is set it into `intent` object, but how about if we want to use Dagger2 for this case?

Update: my sistuation similar with the case of UserScope in this article http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/, but instead of saving the user component in Application class, can I save in an activity, i.e `TaskDetailActivity`?

Comment: When Android destroys and recreates the Activity, will you be able to recreate your context around it?

Comment: Interesting question @JeffBowman, I think we can if using dagger module, all dependencies will be injected with same instance as before in the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components are for grouping objects of a similar lifecycle. While Components may happen to correspond to a particular set of functionality (like a `TaskComponent` for injecting a `TaskActivity` and a `TaskPresenter`) it is not always possible or desirable to insist on only one Component per set of functionality (for instance, insisting on only one `TaskComponent` for all task related activities and dependencies).

Instead, in Dagger 2 re-usability is available through Modules which you can very easily swap in and out of Components. Within the constraints of the advice for organising your Modules for testability in the [Dagger 2 official documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html) you are able to organise Modules congruent with your functionality (e.g., a `TaskModule` for all-task related dependencies). Then, because Components are so lightweight, you can make as many as you like to deal with the different lifecycles of your Activities and so on. Remember also that you can compose Modules using the `Class<?> [] includes()` method inside the `Module` `@interface`.

In your particular scenario, you want to share the `Task` object from a `TaskDetailActivity`. If you held a reference to the `Task` within your `TaskDetailActivity` then that reference will no longer be available when `TaskDetailActivity` is destroyed. While you could try some solution of holding binding the `Task` in a Module and then maintaining a reference to that Module at the app-scope level, you would essentially be doing the same as the `UserScope` at the app-scoped level in the article you have linked. Any kind of solution for sharing the `Task` object between Activity using Dagger 2 would necessarily involve maintaining a reference to the object at the app-scoped level.

Using Dagger 2 doesn't mean that the `new` keyword or serialization/deserialization of `Parcelables` is now wrong and so if your first intuition is to use `Intent` to communicate then I would say that you are right. If you need a more robust solution than directly communicating the `Task`, then you could extract a `TaskRepository` and transmit an `Intent` between Activity that contains the `id` of the `Task` you wish to retrieve. Indeed, some of the [Google Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) have a solution just like this.

Comment: Thank you for very detailed description. I finally decide to keep my Task component at application instance similar `UserComponent` on the link I tagged.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh I'm glad it helped. Thanks for the accept